# Cannot run any gradle commands

Tags: android, react-native, bundle, gradlew

I am trying to run `./gradlew bundleRelease` to get one step further into getting my React-Native app onto the Google Play Store, but I am unable to successfully run the command, getting this as a response

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/nicklanese/Documents/GitHub/KidzNMotionDirectory/KidzNMotionNative/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/nicklanese/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/80b87zhyqy88f68rbm3ba440s).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63
```

The same error also gets thrown when I run any other `./gradlew` command

What can I do to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I solved by upgrading to a snapshot of gradle 7.6
https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-7.6-20221021231540+0000-bin.zip